# Usage of Functions in R

Tags: r, function

This does work:

```
mean(data21m1$TAPSE,na.rm=TRUE)
```

But how can i make this work

```
chara_fun<-function(x) {
mean(data21m1$x,na.rm=TRUE)
}
chara_fun(TAPSE)
```

I think it´s just a little thing but I do not get it.

Comment: *How* doesn't the second form work for you? What is the specific issue you're asking about? "This doesn't work" doesn't really describe the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do what you want, but it involves using `eval` and `substitute` to get to the objects in the parent frame (I'm using `iris` and `mtcars` since we don't have your data frame):

```
charaFun <- function(col) {
  iris_col <- eval(substitute(col), iris, parent.frame())
  mean(iris_col, na.rm=TRUE)
}

charaFun(Sepal.Width)
## [1] 3.057
```

You could (prbly "should") make it more generic if you pass in the data frame as well, and you can set up a default to make it easier to work with:

```
charaFun <- function(col, data=iris) {
  data_col <- eval(substitute(col), data, parent.frame())
  mean(data_col, na.rm=TRUE)
}

charaFun(Sepal.Width)
## [1] 3.057

charaFun(cyl, mtcars)
## [1] 6.188
```

But, the "pass in with quotes" involves less code and is probably more straightforward to work with (despite things like `ggplot`, `plyr` and `dplyr` working the other way):

```
charaFun <- function(col, data=iris) {
  mean(data[,col], na.rm=TRUE)
}

charaFun("Sepal.Width", iris)
## [1] 3.057

charaFun("cyl", mtcars)
## [1] 6.188
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how selecting columns/variables works in R. You need to pass "TAPSE" as a string to your function and then change  `data21m1$x` to `data21m1[, x]` (in the function body). When using a string variable to access a column, you cannot use the dollar sign.

Comment: how do I pass TAPSE as a string to the function?